# PrimeFaces schedule is not viewing events on it

Tags: primefaces

After upgraded PrimeFaces from 7 to 8 schedule is not viewing events on it. Before update, it was working fine.

***Schedule panel in xhtml file;***

```
<p:panel style="margin-right: 3px;margin-bottom: 3px"
                        rendered="#{dashboardBean.renderedAjandam}" closable="true"
                        toggleable="true" id="ajandam" header="Ajandam" resize="true"
                        autosize="true" scrollable="true">
                        <h:form>
                            <p:scrollPanel mode="native" style="border: hidden;height:375px"
                                columnClasses="value">

                                <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{hatirlaticiBean.eventModel}"
                                    locale="tr" timeZone="GMT+3">
                                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
                                        listener="#{hatirlaticiBean.onDateSelect}"
                                        update=":frmeventDialog:eventDetails"
                                        oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
                                    <p:ajax event="eventSelect"
                                        listener="#{hatirlaticiBean.onEventSelect}"
                                        update=":frmeventDialog:eventDetails"
                                        oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
                                    <p:ajax event="eventMove"
                                        listener="#{hatirlaticiBean.onEventMove}"
                                        update=":frmLytCenter:messages" />
                                    <p:ajax event="eventResize"
                                        listener="#{hatirlaticiBean.onEventResize}"
                                        update=":frmLytCenter:messages" />

                                </p:schedule>
                            </p:scrollPanel>
                        </h:form>
                        <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{dashboardBean.onClose}"
                            update=":frmLytCenter,messages" />
                    </p:panel>
```

Comment: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/../migrationguide/8_0?id=schedule

Comment: Tried the changes but still not working as expected. Everything looks fine, eventModel has all events in it but not viewing on schedule. Also there is no error.